# Laravel validate rule if statement is true

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

So I'm using Laravel 5.3 and I have this role in my custom request:

```
return [
    'add_melon' => 'boolean',
    'fruits'    => 'in:banana,apple,pineapple'
];
```

What it does is, it just allows the `fruits` to be one of `banana`, `apple`, and `pineapple`.

Now let's say, that when the `add_melon` is *true*, I want that `fruit` will be able to fill `melon` too. Just like this role:

```
return [
    'fruits'    => 'in:banana,apple,pineapple,melon'
];
```

Is there an existing rule that Laravel supplies for this situations? I know I can just declare rule and check this on my own. But it would be a bit messy.

Comment: Hopefully this will help you out: http://themsaid.com/laravel-advanced-validation-conditionally-adding-rules-20170110/

Comment: @AshMenhennett It is what I need, but the thing is that I cannot use those methods because I've got only the option to fill the rules in a request class.